# Unofficial social media accounts to promote this site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Since we are going to public beta, I just created **unofficial** twitter account at the handle [@StackIpS](https://twitter.com/stackIpS) and facebook account at the handle [@StackIpS](https://www.facebook.com/pg/StackIpS) to promote this community.

I strongly believe that social media plays a huge role in developing the community. We can attract more people to our site and can make a good start in the public beta.

**I need advise on what are all the posts we have to share and need more people who willing to work with me to make this community success.**

> The profile image is didn't set till now as I can't set the logo of this site because it may be a violation of legal things. Not sure but need advice from SE officials

---

#### Update

Since we can't use the favicon, we need an image to use in the profile picture. If anyone willing to submit image, please make as answer to this question.

<sup>*The name pattern is taken from Pets SE (@stackpets)*</sup>

Comment: Yeah, you can't use the site logo because of trademark rules. See [this similar post on Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/691/17) and its answer from a CM.

Comment: Also - I know that Literature.SE's Twitter account is '@StackLit' but SE has said to preferably not do a StackXXX username, and we're still brainstorming for other usernames.

Comment: Two relevant posts on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/274942, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295012/274942

Answer (score 9):

I think it would have been preferable for you to address the community about this *before* creating these accounts. Deciding how to name them, who should be in control of them, how they should be managed... all of that is something we **all** need to be involved in. I appreciate your enthusiasm but I don't think this is the right way to go about it.

As Rand al'Thor noted, [we can't use the official logo](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/698/42) because it's a trademark:

> It's really cool that you want to do this, but unfortunately we can't let you use the site logo for the account. The reasoning comes down to the way current trademark rules work. I won't belabor that point since you're clearly already familiar with our trademark guidance page.

So, in addition to the stuff above, we'd need to create an image to use as the avatar.

Comment: I really thought about requesting a design from this community but forgot to add. Updating the question

Answer (score 4):

**Who has control of these accounts?**

This could potentially be an important issue. If you're the only person running the site's unofficial social media pages, what happens if at some point you have less time for the site? I realise this site doesn't have mods yet, but when pro-tem mods are appointed, I suggest that they *at least* be added as administrators of the Facebook and Twitter accounts.

**Most importantly, thank you!**

I'm not sure why you're getting negativity on this meta post. *Thank you* for stepping up to help promote this community. Enthusiastic users are always appreciated. Even if you jumped the gun a bit (for example, it would probably have been better to wait until we're out of private beta, so that the site is actually *visible* to the internet at large), it's the thought that counts.

Comment: Once pro tem mods are appointed, I will add the interested people to admin panel as I mentioned we need more people to work on this. and I created this because we have 3 more days left to get out of private beta. Anyone with a good history in this site can join the team

Answer (score 4):

We set up a Twitter account for Literature.SE, also. Here's a little advice from what I learned there.

- Let everyone weigh in on the account

  If you want it to be for *the site*, you should have the site with you on this. Over at Lit, first we discussed the matter in chat and *then* the account was created. It's not usually good to make a unilateral decision. However, you've already created them, so that's slightly moot.
- Have more than one person with access.

  Both the creator of the Twitter account and I (with the position of Moderator Pro-tempore on Lit) can log into the account. But we *also* have a special chat room where anyone with access to the room can post a message, and that message (if it gets a star) will get Tweeted. I don't exactly know how this works, but it's good - anyone with access to the room (it's a gallery room - you need special permission to be able to post) can post a message to be Tweeted - it's not just one person representing the site.
- Make it clear that you aren't affiliated with Stack Exchange.

  SE will get quite annoyed at you if you give the impression that your account is affiliated with them. They're not responsible for it. They aren't affiliated with it. *Please* make sure that you state this. I'd also say do *not* call it just 'Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange' - choose a name that says that it's the members of the site and not the site itself.

  It's also better to *not* use the '@StackXXXX' username. Yes, we are @StackLiterature but we're working on changing it (just need some good ideas that weren't already taken!).

I'd also recommend that you have like a feed of new posts in the chat room, like we do, but that's not as important.